# Three.js: changing mesh color results in only 1 face getting affected by the change

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

so i have a model (an assembly from CAD) in GLB format, with many parts, hierarchy and such. What i'm trying to accomplish is highlighting an object (specifically, a part of the assembly) on mouseover.

so the main code that does this is:

```
raycaster.setFromCamera( pointer, camera );
            
                const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

                        if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.set( INTERSECTED.currentColor );

                        INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                        
                        INTERSECTED.currentColor = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();

                        INTERSECTED.material = INTERSECTED.material.clone();
                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xffb300 );

                    }

                } else {

                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.set( INTERSECTED.currentColor );
                    INTERSECTED = null;

                }
```

but unfortunately, the result i get is that only 1 face gets the colour change, the rest of the mesh does not. I have tried many things but i'm kind of a novice on three.js so basically i don't have a clue

Comment: Do you mind sharing the glTF asset in this thread?

Comment: hey, yea, here it is. not exactly the model i'll be using but another that exhibits the same behaviour https://easyupload.io/pcgo0y

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce if use the code from [webgl_interactive_cubes](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes). I've just switched from `pointermove` to `pointerdown`. On selection, the entire sub-mesh gets highlighted.

Comment: Looking at your code, I doubt that the color of a single face is changed. That would only be possible if each triangle of your model has an own material. That is definitely not the case for your shared glTF model.

Comment: mind if i share my entire code? if that snipped i posted is correct i really don't know what else could be wrong... https://pastebin.com/ifvdGF4u

Comment: What you see is the expected behavior. You actually select 3D meshes, not individual triangles/faces. If you want to select a larger area, you have to design the model differently and merge components into bigger ones.

Comment: infact that's what i want but not what i get. see the picture https://ibb.co/7N50KLv that piece is a single mesh. but only 1 face gets coloured

Answer (score 0):

for anybody with the same problem in the future: for some kind of reason the step->glb conversion made a standalone mesh for every object face. So in order to highlight the whole part i had to change the material of every object in object.parent.children